# How to evaluate model using test or train?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was looking through examples on the internet of evaluating model and I found two examples
what is the different between them and how ti interrupt them
I always thought test_X and test_Y is for making prediction and train data is for training and evaluation

```
accuracy = model.evaluate(test_X, test_Y, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy[1]*100))
accuracy


accuracy1 = model.evaluate(train_X, train_Y, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy[1]*100))
accuracy1
```

Comment: If you evaluate using the same data you trained with, you'd expect to see the same results as with training because it's the exact same data. Evaluating generates metrics with respect to labels. Prediction (on the test set) is using unseen data.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). You might be able to delete the post yourself as well.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear about the distinction between train and test sets, you use the training set to optimize your model with, while the test set is used to evaluate your model's generalization.

The reason you would want to evaluate accuracy or performance on both the train and test set is because this gives you lots of clues on how your model performs, and if it does poorly, why.

**Some rules of thumb when comparing train-test performance**

For a good model, you'd expect **both** the train and test accuracy to be **reasonably high**, and the difference between them should be small. This means your model is capable of solving the problem and of generalizing to unseen data.

If **both** train and test accuracy are **low**, that most probably means your model has **high bias**. You probably need to increase the complexity of the model, reduce regularization, or even change the architecture.

If the train set accuracy is **high**, but the test set accuracy is **low**, then you have **high variance**. You should reduce the complexity of the model, or increase regularization.

**NOTE**: Although this kind of analysis can be done with just a train and test set, it is recommended to instead have three sets **(Train, validation, test)** and to use the train and validation sets for bias-variance analysis. This is because you as a model developer will probably try to overfit your model to the validation set, which undermines the idea of testing for generalization.

Comment: This question is not a programming problem and you should not be trying to answer it.

Comment: @Alejandro Aristizábal thank you, this clear things up, what if train accuracy is lower than test does this also mean i have high variance ?